# How to use concrete fonts?

Tags: fonts, sectioning

This MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}

\usepackage{beton}

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
Hello world.

\end{document}
```

produces "Hello world." in Concrete font, but not the section title.  (Without the `polski` package, a bitmap font is used; with it, it's a Type 1 font – at least in TeXlive 2013.  I have no idea why, though this is not a big deal for me here.)

What is the "canonical" way to enable concrete fonts for section titles etc.?  (Note: I'm considering switching to `memoir` or even something else for this document – it's a thesis – so "use `memoir` with such-and-such modifications to section/chapter styles", or some other class, might be a valid answer.)

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I forgot that `\section`s are not only `\large`, but also `\bfseries`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your MWE gives me the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT4/ccr/bx/n' in size <14.4> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT4/cmr/bx/n' tried instead on input line 10.
```

That is there was no bold ("bx") Computer Concrete ("ccr"), so a bold Computer Modern ("cmr") was substituted.

The TeX FAQ has a [question about Concrete](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-concrete) which mentions that there are no bold Concrete fonts, but that it is "generally accepted that the Computer Modern Sans Serif demibold condensed fonts are an adequate substitute", and that you can get those (for `beton`) with

```
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{sbc}
```

Comment: Ha!  I guess that I've just lost the right to ask anyone having LaTeX problems "Did you look at the log file?" ;)

Answer (score 8):

To the best of my knowledge, the `Computer Concrete` font family only comes in medium-weight shapes. In order to get LaTeX to use `Computer Concrete`, rather than `Computer Modern`, as the font in sectioning headers, you must instruct LaTeX to use only medium-weight fonts in such circumstances.

One way to do so is to add the instructions

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\mdseries}
```

to the preamble.

Comment: Thanks!  I decided to accept @pst's answer below because it's more "lightweight", and addresses a more general issue - even though I may use your suggestion instead.

Comment: @mbork - If you do end up employing the `memoir` document class, be sure *not* to load the `sectsty` package. Instead, use `\renewcommand` on `\chaptitlefont`, `\chapnamefont`, and `\chapnumfont` (to `\Huge\mdseries`, say) to use medium-weight fonts for chapter headers. And, use `\setsecheadstyle{\mdseries}` and `\setsubsecheadstyle{\mdseries}` to set a medium font weight for section and subsection headers.

Comment: thanks.  Of course, *if* I use `memoir`, I'll look into its docs;).

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: I misunderstood the question. My answer below is for obtaining a vectorized version of the Concrete fonts. Sorry for the inconvenience.*

You should use the T1 encoding, the recommended 8bits encoding for almost all European languages other than English:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beton}% or ccfonts, or concrete
```

It will load the `cm-super` package which contains a vectorized version of the EC fonts (LaTeX standard fonts for the T1 font encoding) among which the EC Concrete fonts. I don't know the `polski` package, but it is certainly not necessary for the fonts themselves.

Comment: Did you try out your answer? If I add the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the OP's code, I still get CM, and not Concrete, as the font for the section header.

Comment: Simply because there are no bold version of the Concrete fonts, as far as documented in the LaTeX Companion…

Comment: But then your solution doesn't answer the OP's query.

Comment: You are right, I misread it! I thought that the point was to obtain a type 1 version of the Concrete fonts! I edit my answer (which should then be changed in a comment.)

Comment: @fpast: I had the LaTeX Companion once in my hands, for some 3 minutes...  And I forgot (again...) about the boldness of section titles.