# Font types in tcolorbox environment

Tags: fonts, tcolorbox

Is there a way to specify different fonts for both typing and math mode in the `tcolorbox` environment. I want to use the default Computer Modern for most of my document, but use Concrete Fonts and Concrete math to define a theorem in the `tcolorbox` environment.

Comment: `\fontfamily{}\selectfont` is what you need, I think.

Comment: How is the font setup outside the box?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange.  We would love to get something of what you tried to get somewhere near your solution.  So, posting a Minimal Working Example will be highly appreciated in your post.

Answer (score 8):

The manual for `tcolorbox` has a mention for three variables to set the fonts in the title, upper and lower parts of the box.

So, one may use the code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\fon}[1]{\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont}  %% Courtesy: @JouleV
\begin{document}
Normal text using default (Computer Modern Roman) font\ldots\medskip

%
\begin{tcolorbox}[fonttitle=\fon{pbk}\bfseries,
                  fontupper=\fon{ppl}\itshape,
                  fontlower=\fon{put}\scshape,
                  title=Tcolorbox using Bookman font in bold]
Upper part with Palatino font in italics.
\tcblower
Lower part with Utopia font in smallcaps.
\end{tcolorbox}
%
\end{document}
```

to get something like:

[image]

I'm not sure of how to bring in the Concrete font, as it being a Type-I font, requires different implementation.

Comment: You can get Concrete font by font code `ccr`. However, this doesn't change the math font.

Comment: @JouleV But I think it also requires some package like `concrete`, `beton` or `ccfonts` `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as listed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168771/146828).  Maybe the code should also be compiled in LuaLaTeX or XeTeX to have the Concrete font take effect... however I tried several of these options-- to no avail.  It would be great if you could post a solution !